# We feast in Hell's kitchen, we swim through the deep

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, no-computers, cryptic-clues

*We feast in Hell’s kitchen, we swim through the deep,

we wait in the shadows for printers to sleep.

At midnight we come and we jumble your prose.

We pluck out your words because god only knows!*

*And much like our brethren, possessing devices

like pitchforks and cauldrons for punishing vices,

we have a whole toolbox unique to our skills

containing erasers and inkpots and quills!*

*We don’t plan on resting till printers go mad,

till grammar is off and till diction is bad,

till beautiful verses cannot be called song,

and great works of art have all been made wrong!*

**Down**

2. Alpha males push around Ben (4)
3. Our troops will win because the opposition has a wormy… (4)
4. I have so many nautical antiques that I need moorage (4)
5. They used a hut in an attempt to catch the oversized moth (4)
6. He found the loon and finally got the wrinkles out of his shirt (4)
7. Letter writing is a lot (4)
8. I heard sounder, then saw the lightning a moment later (4)
9.  The dried his bladder in an alley beside the tavern (7)
13. The mythological chimes little study by cryptozoologists today (5)
15. According to the stage directions, when the two are offended, they gait (7)
16. In addition to his scientific discoveries, Leonardo also mat (4)
17. When it comes to credit, S&P and Moody's dating (5)
18. At the renaissance fair he ate a tag of lamb (5)
19. Without any moo, let me introduce your speaker (4)
20. The exterminator guarantees that there will be zest problems after his visit (4)

**Across**

1. Because she raps them on the knuckles, many Catholic schoolboys fun (7)
10. Prepare the δλπχτχ, squirm is under attack! (8)
11. Greener grails it's the λωδτπ side (6)
12. After hiking all day up Mont Blanc, I finally reached the top of the whips (4)
14. The drawing of the λξμ was okay, but the linage was atrocious (5)
21. Like all of its μind, the views not its food (5)
22. Roman engineers designed exquisite γξπφδτχ (5)
23. The γξμτχ to yoga was beginning to stink (5)
24. Unfortunately, the portable bridge doesn't χifω (7)

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The across clues were decoded using

> the Greek letters hidden in dark gray around the grid.

The alchemical symbols

> are "virtual intersections" - two letters next to the same symbol must be the same.

Here's the full grid:

> [image]
>  The orange letters anagram to HAIL SATAN, our solution.

DOWN

2.

> Alpha males push around Be**ta me**n (4)

3.

> Our troops will win because the opposition has a wor**se ar**my… (4)

4.

> I have so many nautical antiques that I need mo**re st**orage (4)

5.

> They used a hu**ge ne**t in an attempt to catch the oversized moth (4)

6.

> He found the lo**st ir**on and finally got the wrinkles out of his shirt (4)

7.

> Letter writing is a lo**st ar**t (4)

8.

> I heard so**me th**under, then saw the lightning a moment later (4)

9.

> The dr**unk empt**ied his bladder in an alley beside the tavern (7)

13.

> The mythological chim**era se**es little study by cryptozoologists today (5)

15.

> According to the stage directions, when the two are offended, they ga**sp and ex**it (7)

16.

> In addition to his scientific discoveries, Leonardo also ma**de ar**t (4)

17.

> When it comes to credit, S&P and Moody's d**o the r**ating (5) *(Thanks, Sconibulus!)*

18.

> At the renaissance fair he ate a ta**sty le**g of lamb (5)

19.

> Without any mo**re ad**o, let me introduce your speaker (4)

20.

> The exterminator guarantees that there will be ze**ro pe**st problems after his visit (4)

ACROSS

1.

> Because she raps them on the knuckles, many Catholic schoolboys f**ear the n**un (7)

10.

> Prepare the horses, squir**e! The real**m is under attack! (8)

11.

> Greener gr**ass ent**ails it's the other side (6)

12.

> After hiking all day up Mont Blanc, I finally reached the top of the whi**te Al**ps (4)

14.

> The drawing of the oak was okay, but the lin**den im**age was atrocious (5)

21.

> Like all of its kind, the vi**per ch**ews not its food (5)

22.

> Roman engineers designed exquisite mar**ble ar**ches (5)

23.

> The ma**t he ta**kes to yoga was beginning to stink (5)

24.

> Unfortunately, the portable bridge doesn't s**pan the r**ift (7)

Answer (score 6):

Right:
DOWN:

7.

> STAR Letter writing is a lo(ST AR)t

8.

> METH-  I heard so(ME TH)under, then saw the lightning a moment later (4)

16.

> DEAR- In addition to his scientific discoveries, Leonardo also ma(DE AR)t

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's get this started. I spy some

> Printer's Devilry ...

**DOWN**
3.

> SEAR -  Our troops will win because the opposition has a wor**se ar**my

**ACROSS**
1.

> EARTHEN - Because she raps them on the knuckles, many Catholic schoolboys f**ear the n**un (7)